# Location of VB.NET "source" code, similar to Java's JDK src.zip

Tags: vb.net, decompiler

Does VB.NET have anything similar to Java's JDK source code? When I used to work in Eclipse, I could right click and view the generated code, or "look under-the-hood" so to speak. I found this feature very helpful in understanding what was happening behind the scenes, and it helped me to write better, more simplified code.
I have so far been working with Visual Studio 2010's Object Browser, and I have also been looking at the generated designer files, but these often do not drill down far enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best program to do this is called .NET Reflector and you can download it from here: http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

It lets you see executables and DLL's under the hood

Answer (score 0):

ScottGu has an old blog post about this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx

You can also use the .NET Reflector to peek into the code for any .NET dll, but keep in mind it won't look like the code in Visual Studio :)

http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Comment: Thank you for the blog post link--I was very happy to learn that Microsoft has decided to open up some of their source code!